# Close ion-select after open it programmatically

Tags: ionic-framework

I use @ViewChild to open programmatically a Select box and once is open, I can't close it with the conventional buttons (Done or Cancel). Somebody have a solution to close the select-popup.

This problem only occur when i'm trigger the other select box in a other, like this:

```
<ion-select #secondSelect 
     [(ngModel)]="test" 
     (ionChange)="openSecondSelect($event)">
     ...
</ion-select>

<ion-select #secondSelect>...</ion-select>

openSecondSelect(event) {
     this.secondSelect.open();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I temporarily solved my problem with a setTimeout

```
openSecondSelect(event) {
     setTimeout(() => {
         this.secondSelect.open();
     }, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved permanently with the below code

```
constructor(private popoverCtrl: PopoverController) {
}
public closeIonSelectprogrammatically(){
    this.popoverCtrl.dismiss();
}
```